# Summing elements of a set of numbers to a given number

Tags: algorithm

I have been battling to put up an algorithm to solve this problem.
Let say i have a set of number `{1, 2, 5}` and each element of the this set as unlimited supply, and i given another number 6, then ask to determine the number of ways you can sum the elements to get the number 6. For illustration purpose i do this

```
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 6

1 + 1 + 2 + 2 = 6

2 + 2 + 2 = 6

1 + 5 = 6

1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2 = 6
```

So in this case the program will output 5 as the number of ways. Again let say you are to find the sum for 4,

```
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 4

2 + 2 = 4

1 + 1 + 2 = 4
```

In this case the algorithm will output 3 as the number of way

Comment: This is similar to sum of subsets problem .  I am sure you have to use branch and bound method. Learn more about sum of subsets 
  [1]: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subset-sum-problem-dp-25/

Comment: Why isn't the [partition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) `1+3` allowed for `4`?

Comment: @Spencer only {1,2,5} allowed

Comment: 1+1+2 would be allowed

Comment: yes 1 + 1 + 2 would be allow too

Comment: also 1+1+1+1+2 to sum 6

Comment: This is a standard infinite [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), commonly used to teach dynamic programming. Learn about dynamic programming and you'll be able to solve this problem yourself.

Answer (score 4):

This is similar to sum of subsets problem . I am sure you have to use branch and bound method or backtracking method.

1)Create a state space tree which consist of all possible cases.

```
                        0
                    /   |   \
                   1    2     5
                 / | \
                1  2  5 ........
```

2) Continue the process until the sum of nodes in depth first manner is greater or equal to your desired number.

3) Count the no. of full branches that satisfy your condition.

The python implementation of similar problem can be found [here](https://assil.me/2017/11/20/subset-sum-branch-bound.html).

Comment: Please include the content of the external site in your answer. At least to an extend such that the answer fully solves the issue without following an external link (see [answer]).

Answer (score 3):

This is a good problem to use [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) and [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) techniques.  Here is an implementation in Python using the **top-down** approach ([memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)) to avoid doing the same calculation multiple times:

```py
# Remember answers for subsets
cache = {}

# Return the ways to get the desired sum from combinations of the given numbers
def possible_sums(numbers, desired_sum):
  # See if we have already calculated this possibility
  key = (tuple(set(numbers)), desired_sum)
  if key in cache:
    return cache[key]

  answers = {}
  for n in numbers:
    if desired_sum % n == 0:
      # The sum is a multiple of the number
      answers[tuple([n] * (desired_sum / n))] = True

    if n < desired_sum:
      for a in possible_sums(numbers, desired_sum - n):
        answers[tuple([n] + a)] = True

  cache[key] = [list(k) for k in answers.iterkeys()]
  return cache[key]

# Return only distinct combinations of sums, ignoring order
def unique_possible_sums(numbers, desired_sum):
  answers = {}
  for s in possible_sums(numbers, desired_sum):
    answers[tuple(sorted(s))] = True
  return [list(k) for k in answers.iterkeys()]

for s in unique_possible_sums([1, 2, 5], 6):
  print '6: ' + repr(s)

for s in unique_possible_sums([1, 2, 5], 4):
  print '4: ' + repr(s)
```

Comment: Sorry to ask, did you run this script successfully? because i am having a hard time running it.

Comment: Yes @AnanaAristotle it works fine for me.  What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

For smaller target number(~1000000) and 1000{supply} n try this:

The supply of numbers you have

```
supply {a,b,c....}
```

The target you need

```
steps[n]
```

1 way to get to 0 use nothing

```
steps[0]=1
```

Scan till target number

```
for i from 1 to n:
  for each supply x:
if i - x >=0 
     steps[i] += steps[i-x]
```

Steps at n will contain the number of ways

```
steps[n]
```

Visualization of the above:
    supply {1, 2, 5} , target 6

```
i = 1, x=1 and steps required is 1
i = 2, x=1 and steps required is 1
i = 2, x=2 and steps required is 2
i = 3, x=1 and steps required is 2
i = 3, x=2 and steps required is 3
i = 4, x=1 and steps required is 3
i = 4, x=2 and steps required is 5
i = 5, x=1 and steps required is 5
i = 5, x=2 and steps required is 8
i = 5, x=5 and steps required is 9
i = 6, x=1 and steps required is 9
i = 6, x=2 and steps required is 14
i = 6, x=5 and steps required is 15
```

Some Java Code

```
   private int test(int targetSize, int supply[]){
        int target[] = new int[targetSize+1];
        target[0]=1;
        for(int i=0;i<=targetSize;i++){
            for(int x:supply){
                if(i-x >= 0){
                    target[i]+=target[i-x];
                }
            }
        }
        return target[targetSize];
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
      System.err.println(test(12, new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6}));
    }
```